# trying to allow user to input CSV file for data sheet to create decision tree

Tags: python, decision-tree

Trying to allow the user to input a CSV file but my problem is my decision tree is not printing the way its supposed to be: [this is how my tree is supposed to come out like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjUA5.png)

Code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Prompt the user to enter the file path of the CSV
file_path = input("Enter the file path of the CSV: ")

# Read the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Separate features and target
X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = data.iloc[:, -1].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X_encoded_train = np.empty(X_train.shape)
X_encoded_test = np.empty(X_test.shape)

for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):
    X_encoded_train[:, i] =     label_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[:, i])

for i in range(X_test.shape[1]):
    X_encoded_test[:, i] = label_encoder.fit_transform(X_test[:, i])

dtc = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy",     min_impurity_decrease=0.1)
dtc.fit(X_encoded_train, y_train)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
tree.plot_tree(dtc, feature_names=data.columns[:-1].tolist(),  class_names=np.unique(y), filled=True)
plt.show()

y_pred = dtc.predict(X_encoded_test)
print("Classification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

The CSV is a data sheet and this is the array for it

```
dataset2 = np.array([
    ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'some', '$$$', 'no', 'yes', 'french', '0-10', 'yes'],
    ['yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'full', '$', 'no', 'no', 'thai', '30-60', 'no'],
    ['no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'some', '$', 'no', 'no', 'burger', '0-10', 'yes'],
    ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'full', '$', 'yes', 'no', 'thai', '10-30', 'yes'],
    ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'full', '$$$', 'no', 'yes', 'french', '>60', 'no'],
    ['no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'some', '$$', 'yes', 'yes',  'italian', '0-10', 'yes'],
    ['no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'none', '$', 'yes', 'no', 'burger', '0-10', 'no'],
    ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'some', '$$', 'yes', 'yes', 'thai', '0-10', 'yes'],
    ['no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'full', '$', 'yes', 'no', 'burger', '>60', 'no'],
    ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'full', '$$$', 'no', 'yes', 'italian', '10-30', 'no'],
    ['no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'none', '$', 'no', 'no', 'thai', '0-10', 'no'],
    ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'full', '$', 'no', 'no', 'burger', '30-60', 'yes']
])
```

But it shows like this ->> [wrong tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su5rS.png)